# how to remove a unconnected points when i mouseout from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

i need to remove unconnected points when i mouseout from canvas. I just draw lines when mousemove using moveTo and LineTo. when mouseout from canvas have to omit the unconnected points.

Here is code for jquery:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        var canvas = $('#canvas');
        var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
        var clicked = false;
        var b=0;
        var storedLines = [];
        var storedLine = {};
        var mouse = {
            x: -1,
            y: -1
        }

        var parentOffset = $('#canvas').offset();
        canvas.click(function(e) {
           if (b==1)
           {
              $(this).unbind(e);
           }
           else
           {
              clicked = true;
              mouse.x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
              mouse.y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
              context.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
              if (clicked) {
                 storedLines.push({
                      startX: storedLine.startX,
                      startY: storedLine.startY,
                      endX: mouse.x,
                      endY: mouse.y
                 });
              }
              storedLine.startX = mouse.x;
              storedLine.startY = mouse.y;
              $(this).mousemove(function(k) {
                 context.clearRect(0, 0, 960, 500);
                 context.beginPath();
                 context.strokeStyle = "blue";
                 for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
                    var v = storedLines[i];
                    context.moveTo(v.startX, v.startY);
                    context.lineTo(v.endX, v.endY);
                    context.stroke();
                 }
                 context.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                 context.lineTo(k.pageX - parentOffset.left, k.pageY - parentOffset.top);
                 context.stroke();

                 context.closePath();
             });
          } 
    });
    $('#canvas').mouseout(function(e){
         $(this).unbind("mousemove");

         b=1;
    });
```

});

HTML code:

```
  <html>
  <body>
     <canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=600 ></canvas>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: tried basic math ? http://www.wikihow.com/Algebraically-Find-the-Intersection-of-Two-Lines . With two loops.

Comment: Unconnected points or May be disjoint lines? And unconnected points is set of single separate points?

Comment: disjoint lines...in the above code mentioned that when clicked, it fire the mousemove event and draw lines inbetween moveTo and LineTo. suppose when mouseout from canvas i dont want to draw line..

Comment: There's an edge case (pun intended) you didn't address.  What should happen when the mouse goes out of the canvas and then comes back on the canvas. (1) draw 2 separate lines, (2) one line connected at the last on-canvas points, (3) one line connected at the interpolated points where the mouse went off and back on the canvas, (4) invalidate the whole line and draw nothing, (5) something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to clarify the code : Have one part that deals only with the mouse, and another part that deals only with the lines.
This way you will have a much better view on what will happen on each event.
I started a bit to clarify the code, you should even make a class handling lines (which will be very useful if you handle several of them).

jsbin is here : http://jsbin.com/eseTODo/2/edit?js,output

```
var canvas = $('#canvas');
var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

// -----------------------------------------
//       Mouse

var clicked = false;
var onCanvas = false;

var mouse = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
}
var parentOffset = $('#canvas').offset();

canvas.mousedown(function (e) {
    clicked = true;
    if (!onCanvas) return;
    mouse.x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    addPoint(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    clearScreen();
    drawLines();
});

canvas.mouseup(function (e) {
    clicked = false;
    if (!onCanvas) return;
});

canvas.mousemove(function (e) {
    if (!onCanvas) return;
    clearScreen();
    drawLines();
    drawPendingLine(e.pageX - parentOffset.left,
    e.pageY - parentOffset.top);
});

canvas.mouseout(function (e) {
    onCanvas = false;
    clearScreen();
    drawLines();
    clearLines();
});

canvas.mouseenter(function (e) {
    onCanvas = true;
});

// -----------------------------------------
//       Lines

var storedLines = [];
var storedLine = {};
var startedALine = false;

function clearLines() {
    storedLines.length = 0;
    startedALine = false;
}

function addPoint(x, y) {
    if (startedALine) {
        storedLines.push({
            startX: storedLine.startX,
            startY: storedLine.startY,
            endX: x,
            endY: y
        });
    }
    startedALine = true;
    storedLine.startX = x;
    storedLine.startY = y
}

function drawLines() {
    context.strokeStyle = "blue";
    if (!startedALine) return;
    if (!storedLines.length) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
        var v = storedLines[i];
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(v.startX, v.startY);
        context.lineTo(v.endX, v.endY);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }
    context.stroke();
}

function drawPendingLine(lastX, lastY) {
    if (!startedALine) return;
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "green";
    context.moveTo(storedLine.startX, storedLine.startY);
    context.lineTo(lastX, lastY);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
}


function clearScreen() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you set a flag like

```
var hasLeftCanvas = false;
```

and set it to true when you leave the canvas?

```
canvas.onmouseleave = function() {
    hasLeftCanvas = true;
}
```

and then, in your script:

```
$(this).mousemove(function(k) {
    if(!hasLeftCanvas) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 960, 500);
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "blue";
        for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
            var v = storedLines[i];
            context.moveTo(v.startX, v.startY);
            context.lineTo(v.endX, v.endY);
            context.stroke();
         }
         context.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
         context.lineTo(k.pageX - parentOffset.left, k.pageY - parentOffset.top);
         context.stroke();

         context.closePath();
     }
 });
```

remember to set it back to false when the cursor re enters the canvas